# How do i parse a dictionary from a uri?

Tags: c#, web-services, http

I'm trying to write a webservice method that pulls a string/string dictionary from a uri. I originally wrote the signature like this, hoping that it would be smart enough to parse the dictionary itself:

```
([FromUri]Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
```

The query string in the uri looks like this: ?KeyForDictionary=ValueForDictionary

When I moused over the "parameters", it was showing null. So next I decided to try and accept a string, instead of a dictionary, and parse it out to a dictionary in the body of the method. When I moused over the string... it showed a key-value pair!! Can anyone tell me how to either a) get a dictionary from the uri, or b) manipulate this mysterious "key-value/string" object so I can pass my stuff to the DB? Also, any links you guys have on understanding what's going on here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say "webservice," are you talking about ASP.NET Web API?

Comment: If a is an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>, you can convert it to a dictionary with a.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value).

Comment: @totem I'm trying that. mousing over the "parameters" in the signature gives me a Count 0. So far, out of anything I've tried, putting a string in the signature is the only thing that gives me a result.

Comment: Ok, I just did a Quickwatch on parameters. Its saying it's a string, object dictionary. I would love to just use that, but it's calling a method that expects a dictionary and won't build.

Comment: What is the signature you're using for string binding? if it's just `[FromUri] string parameters` then with the default value providers that still shouldn't bind as your key is `KeyForDictionary` not `parameters`. Can you add some more context (including confirming that you're using Web API)?

Comment: @AntP Yes, using Web API. I've tried both with and without [FromUri] with the same result.